# Getting error Invalid column name display_name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, when I run the query shown below, I am getting error

> Invalid column name display_name

Can anyone please help me? How can I resolve this problem?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    'Nbr of RAPs' AS display_name, 
    MonthRap AS MonthStart, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT tb_Episode.id) AS total
FROM   
    tb_Episode
WHERE  
    (BranchID = '244' or BranchID = '242' or BranchID = '240' or BranchID = '243')
    AND RAPClaimDate IS NOT NULL
    AND RAPClaimDate >= '2017-01-01'
    AND RAPClaimDate < '2018-2-01'
    AND tb_Episode.CustID =  '27'
    AND tb_Episode.DTR >= 0
    AND tb_Episode.DTR <= '30'
    AND tb_Episode.PayorType =  'Medicare Traditional' 
GROUP BY 
    display_name, MonthRap
ORDER BY 
    tb_Episode.MonthRap ASC
```

Comment: Remove display_name from group by clause (It is static string and using it in group by clause has no meaning).

Comment: As @BhatiaAshish says, you cannot use ii. if you wanna use display_name in the group statement you need a second select with another group statement.

Comment: Check this to understand why is not working: [Order of execution of a Query](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution)

Comment: Thanks to all its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a constant, so you do not need to aggregate by it.  The reason for this error is that column aliases are not allowed in the `group by`.  There are other issues as well with the query.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT 'Nbr of RAPs' as display_name, 
       e.MonthRap as MonthStart, 
       count(*) as total
FROM tb_Episode e
WHERE e.BranchID IN (244, 242, 240, 243) AND
      e.RAPClaimDate is not null AND
      e.RAPClaimDate >= '2017-01-01' AND
      e.RAPClaimDate < '2018-02-01' AND
      e.tb_Episode.CustID = 27 AND
      e.tb_Episode.DTR >= 0 AND
      e.tb_Episode.DTR <= 30 AND
      e.tb_Episode.PayorType =  'Medicare Traditional' 
GROUP BY MonthRap
ORDER BY e.MonthRap asc;
```

Notes:

- I removed the `DISTINCT`.  Presumably, `id` is already unique in the table.  If it is not, then use `DISTINCT`.  However, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is typically a bit slower than `COUNT(*)`.
- I replaced the first condition with `IN` -- simpler to read to to write.
- I removed single quotes around what look like number constants.  Don't turn numbers into strings, if you intend a number.
- I changed the format of the dates to be YYYY-MM-DD.  Use a fixed length format, rather than dispensing with 0s for low numbered months and days.
- I also added a table alias and qualified all column names.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be :

```
SELECT 'Nbr of RAPs' as display_name, 
       MonthRap as MonthStart, 
       count(DISTINCT tb_Episode.id) as total
FROM   tb_Episode
WHERE  (BranchID = '244' or BranchID = '242' or BranchID = '240' or BranchID = '243')
AND    RAPClaimDate is not null
AND    RAPClaimDate >= '2017-01-01'
AND    RAPClaimDate < '2018-2-01'
AND    tb_Episode.CustID =  '27'
AND    tb_Episode.DTR >= 0
AND    tb_Episode.DTR <= '30'
AND    tb_Episode.PayorType =  'Medicare Traditional' 
GROUP BY MonthRap
ORDER BY tb_Episode.MonthRap asc
```

Please notice the aliased column 'display_name' is removed from the `group by`. You can't add the column name `display_name` in group by because it is created and aliased in the `SELECT` query.